# Using AlarmManager() to call a function

Tags: android

This is my code but this calls my activity instead of a function i want ,this code runs under a function that is inturn made in a Service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, abc.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(Server.this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager almmgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
        int min1 = cldr.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        cldr.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cldr.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        almmgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cldr.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

basically I would like to take inputs from 2 timepickers and when the difference of times between these 2 is achieved then call a function which does some control stuff!

Comment: Is `abc.class` an `Activity`? You need a `BroadCastReceiver` if you want to do some logic *then* talk to services, launch other things, etc.

Comment: Yes abc.class an Activity,I'm running this in a function in service and I'm able to access the needed stuff from Activity as wanted, the values i mean time from time pickers is provided to the function of the service under parameter's , **So I just want to know how can I use intents etc to call a specific function in the service itself?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I just want to know how can I use intents etc to call a specific function in the service itself?

You don't, at least not directly.

You can create a service, and you can use a `getService()` `PendingIntent` in order to have `AlarmManager` invoke that service. However, you will get control in `onStartCommand()`, not some other "specific function in the service itself". You are welcome to call some other "specific function in the service itself" from `onStartCommand()` if you wish, but please bear in mind that you are on the main application thread and therefore cannot do very much. If you have a lot of work to do, you might consider creating an `IntentService` instead of a plain `Service`, so that you can get control on a background thread (in `onHandleIntent()`).

Comment: I just need a very small thing to do so as such I will stick to the Service, Any example?

Comment: @user1898249: I do not have an example of using a plain `Service` with `AlarmManager`, as that is rather odd. Here is one using a fairly small `IntentService`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Scheduled

Comment: Do I have to bind the service with the activity its linked with?

Comment: I was able to get connected or start a service and print a toast onCreate() with alarm manager but I want also to send data, will putExtra & getExtra work?

Comment: @user1898249: "Do I have to bind the service with the activity its linked with?" -- no. "will putExtra & getExtra work?" -- yes.

Comment: I tried putExtra() and getExtra() however when I just put getIntent().getExtra(); in onCreate() of service It always shows a red line under getIntent() so a error in it! what to do?

Comment: @user1898249: Delete `onCreate()`. Move the code to `onStartCommand()`. Use the `Intent` passed to `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Initially I was using the onStartCommand() only and not onCreate() but it was never called as I never saw the toast too!

Comment: @user1898249: I guarantee that `onStartCommand()` is called when a service is invoked by a `getService()` `PendingIntent`. For further assistance on this question, please consult the documentation (or a good book). Also, do not use a `Toast` for debugging like this -- log a message to LogCat.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example I cobbled together from a few different projects and may work for those coming across this question:

```
    BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
             @Override
             public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {     
                 Toast.makeText(c, "A toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
    };
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.example.filterMe") );

    AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.example.filterMe"),0);

    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 30000, pi); // 30 second repeat for testing
```